# Is it possible to do fuzzy filter search? (filter on a field for a set of values)

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-filter

I came from this issue https://github.com/carltongibson/django-filter/issues/919, here is what happened:

I want to do some fuzzy search on a list via django-filter (certain list search and single fuzzy search is ok).

First, the product model:

```
from django.db import models


class Product(models.Model):
    ...
    name = models.CharField(max_length=16)
    type = models.CharField(max_length=16)
    ...
```

and two products stored in database:

```
{
  "name": "tomato",
  "type": "vegetable"
}

{
  "name": "orange",
  "type": "fruit"
}
```

and serializer:

```
from rest_framework import serializers

from .models import Product


class ProductSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    name = serializers.CharField()
    type = serializers.CharFIeld()

    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = '__all__'
```

then [ListFilter](https://github.com/carltongibson/django-filter/issues/137):

```
import django_filters
from django_filters.fields import Lookup

from .models import Product


class ListFilter(django_filters.Filter):
    def filter(self, qs, value):
        value_list = value.split(u',')
        return super(ListFilter, self).filter(qs, Lookup(value_list, 'in'))
```

then view (I put the `ListFilter` at `utils.django_filters`):

```
from rest_framework import generics
from django_filters import rest_framework as filters

from utils.django_filters import ListFilter

from .models import Product
from .serializers import ProductSerializer


class ProductFilter(filters.FilterSet):
    type = ListFilter(name='type')

    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = {
            'type': ['exact', 'contains'],
        }


class ProductList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = Product.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ProductSerializer
    filter_backends = (filters.DjangoFilterBackend,)
    filter_class = ProductFilter
```

finally url:

```
from django.urls import path

from . import views


path('product-list', views.ProductList.as_view(), name='product-list')
```

Below is the test cases and results:

`GET /api/product/product-list?type=fruit` -> `[orange]`

`GET /api/product/product-list?type=vegetable` -> `[tomato]`

`GET /api/product/product-list?type=fruit,vegetable` -> `[orange, tomato]`

`GET /api/product/product-list?type__contains=fru` -> `[orange]`

`GET /api/product/product-list?type__contains=vege` -> `[tomato]`

`GET /api/product/product-list?type__contains=fru,vege` -> `[]`

`GET /api/product/product-list?type__contains=fruit,vegetable` -> `[]`

I expect the last two results be `[orange, tomato]`, is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally got this solved according to [rpkilby](https://github.com/rpkilby)'s [answer](https://github.com/carltongibson/django-filter/issues/919):

```
from functools import reduce
from operator import or_

from django.db.models import Q
from django_filters import Filter, CharFilter
from django_filters.fields import Lookup
from django_filters.filters import BaseCSVFilter


SPLIT_SIGN = u','


class ListFilter(Filter):
    def filter(self, qs, value):
        value_list = value.split(SPLIT_SIGN)
        return super(ListFilter, self).filter(qs, Lookup(value_list, 'in'))


def gen_fuzzy_list_filter(attr_name):
    class CharListFilter(BaseCSVFilter, CharFilter):
        @staticmethod
        def filter(qs, value):
            # BaseCSVFilter produces/validates a list of values
            value_list = SPLIT_SIGN.join(value).split(SPLIT_SIGN)
            queries = [Q(**{attr_name: val}) for val in value_list]
            return qs.filter(reduce(or_, queries))

    return CharListFilter
```

then in filter:

```
class ProductFilter(filterset.FilterSet):
    type = ListFilter(name='type')
    type__contains = gen_fuzzy_list_filter('type__contains')(field_name='type', lookup_expr='contains')
```

Answer (score 1):

Try Django [Fulltext Search](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/postgres/search/) like TrigramSimilarity search, but only if your DB is PostgreSQL.

For other DBs an external python package running fuzzy search on querysets can be used.